# Does two php.ini files mean that I installed PHP twice?

Tags: php

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 with lampp installed and working correctly. Since I couldn't install xDebug as PHP module for use in Eclipse I searched a bit and stumbled upon two different php.ini files. One is located in  /etc/php5/cli, and the other one in /opt/lampp/etc.
a call to PHP's phpinfo() says that it loaded config file from /opt/lampp/etc, but when I run "php --ini" it says that loaded one is from /etc/php5/cli. Do I need to uninstall the one from /etc?

Answer (score 0):

The `cli` in `/etc/php5/cli` stands for `Command Line Interface`, so it uses *that* `php.ini` file when you're invoking php from the command line.

The `php.ini` in `/opt/lampp/etc` is the one that lampp installed and, as you noticed, is the one that apache uses for web requests. (For those not using a lampp package, you'll likely see apache's `php.ini` in `/etc/php5/apache2/`)

PHP *does* act a little differently in each environment, which is why the two config files are necessary. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php) for more info there.

If you never use php from the command line (don't forget about cron jobs!) then you can ignore the one in `/etc/php/cli`, but no you shouldn't uninstall either.